# Convert "Day Date Of Month YYYY" To YYYY-MM-DD In Php

Tags: php, date, datetime

How to convert "Friday 20th of March 2015" into "2015-03-20" in Php ?

Options Tried (Failed):

```
$time = strtotime(stripslashes("Friday 20th of March 2015"));
echo date("Y-m-d",$time);


$time = strtotime("Friday 20th of March 2015");
echo date("Y-m-d",$time);
```

Option 2 (Failed):

```
$old_date = date('Friday 20th of March 2015');           
$old_date_timestamp = strtotime($old_date);
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', $old_date_timestamp);   
echo $new_date;
```

Option 3 (Failed):

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l d of F Y', 'Friday 20th of March 2015');
$new_date_format = $date->format('Y-m-d');
echo $new_date_format;
```

Duplicate Entries That Didn't Work Out:
[How to convert "Day, dd Month yyyy" to "yyyy-mm-dd" in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25326134/how-to-convert-day-dd-month-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd-in-php)

[Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Comment: Duplicate Options Didn't Help As Well. (Code & Sample Provided.)

Comment: Your given format is wrong `Friday 20th of March 2015` will be `Friday 20 March 2015`, and then it will be converted correctly. so it's not problem of `date()` or `strtotime()` .it's the problem of the data that you given.

Comment: Are you sure it didn't helped? Have you read all answers?

Comment: The data which needs to be converted is `Friday 20th of March 2015`. This format cannot be changed since this is a third party format.

Comment: @Rizier123 - I am updating the question with all the answers that didn't work from the duplicate page link provided.

Comment: @ArijitAich How about specifying the correct date format: http://3v4l.org/uo6vN ?

Comment: @Rizier123 - It Worked. I have updated the question with the correct answer. Would be great if you could remove the duplicate tag, since its not a duplicate entry to the link provided. Thank You.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11435513/3933332 <- Seems like exactly what you use now. <- And this answer is in the dupe

Comment: Yes. As you can see, i have already mentioned in the question, the links and answers that didn't work out since the beginning.

Comment: @fvu We can't have every possible date format as an answer..

Comment: @fvu If you feel like it, then go for it OR OP can answer his own question now.

Answer (score 1):

This Code Works:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('l dS \o\f F Y', 'Friday 20th of March 2015');
        $new_date_format = $date->format('Y-m-d');
        echo $new_date_format;
```

Comment: You should use `'l dS \o\f F Y'` as the format specifier as it will cope not only with `20th`, but also with eg `2nd` and `1st`